# Basically: how do you get Open Feint X to work? (iOS)

Tags: ios, openfeint, ofx

I'm currently integrating Open Feint X in my iOS project, with a custom store, trying to synchronize data between OFX servers, to download new contents... and all I have to do it is their sample application, with no comment, and a very basic API...
Would anyone have some clues to give, maybe a useful link that Google did not reveal to me, or anything that could help me to understand which functions I should call and where ?

Thanks,

Grhyll.

EDIT: They are currently working on a doc. However, I've managed to make a few steps further, so if you have questions, don't hesitate to ask here, and if I can I'll answer...